# I want add custom column for sidebar all page in Magento

Tags: magento, sidebar

I want add my custom sidebar next right column all page.

Please check this link: http://www.wildbuilder.com/images/Untitled-1-Recovered.png

(I explain using image.)

There are featured products in the mini sidebar.

I don't want include the mini sidebar into right column. next to right column :)

I already made featured-products.phtml at /catalog/product/ folder.

And I created cms block, featured_products and I put in this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/featured-products.phtml"}}
```

And I added code at page.xml like this.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
            <block type="cms/block" name="featured_products">
                            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>featured_products</block_id></action>
                </block>
        </block>
```

Then I added code in 2columns-right.phtml at /template/page/ folde.

like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <div class="main-container col2-right-layout">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        <div class="main">                
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
<?php //my slidebar ?>
<div style="float:right;width:92px;vertical-align:top;background-color:#000;margin:-766px 110px 0 0;">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('featured_products') ?>
</div>
```

But my sidebar is not showing.

How Can I Do???

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: remove `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('featured_products') ?>
` line before implement the below code.

Comment: I updated my article. Please check it and I always clear the cache after edited my code.

Answer (score 2):

Also, try the following in 2-columns-right.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(featured_products)->toHtml() ?>
```

Comment: I try it but anything is showing.
So I changed code 'test' instead {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/featured-products.phtml"}}.
Then the 'test' is showing. haha
I think toHtml is not working this situation.

Comment: Whilst this is the correct way to create a block on the fly using PHP. It is not the correct Magento way to add a default block, it is not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

No no no. Never edit the 2col-right, left or any other ./page/ template file for a modification such as this. You should also not be making changes in page.xml

What you need to do is understand layout handles on Magento. As your change relates specifically to catalogue, you should edit

```
catalog.xml
```

Then within that file, you can utilise the  layout handle - which means, it appears, by default, everywhere.

```
<default>
  <reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/featured-products.phtml" name="featuredprods" before="-">
      <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>4</category_id></action>
    </block>
  </reference>
</default>
```

***There is no need for a phtml modification, or a CMS block or an edit of page.xml***

Comment: my front page cannot be found now!!
First I change my catalog.xml file and refresh my cache then my front page is not working!!
Page cannot be found!! But back-end is working.

Comment: Apologies, there was a slight typo, please copy the amended code above.

Comment: nothing to changed.
And please check below link.
http://www.wildbuilder.com/images/Untitled-1-Recovered.png
I explain using image. I don't want include the mini sidebar into right culumn. next to right culumn. :)

Comment: Right, now you've edited your question, it makes a lot more sense. So you want to add another column, outside of the page width? In that case, you are going to have to make the changes to the main template files (2col-right,2col-left,1col,3col), page.xml and category.xml. That way you can define a new area (eg. outsideright), reference it and add content to it.

Comment: Yes. You perfectly understood!! But I need to know where I input what code for example. could you show me the example ?? Please.